# Combine two streamplots with different position dependent color functions

Tags: color, streams

Building from replies to other posts I have come up with a combination of two stream plots which has

1. a position dependent color function for stream lines which the same for the two plots
2. a way to "feed" other different style options to one plot and the other

like so

```
Show[StreamPlot[{3 x (2 x - 1), -6 x (1 - y) y}, {x, 0, 0.5}, {y, 0, 
     1}, StreamColorFunction -> (Blend[{Cyan, Darker[Cyan], 
         Lighter[Cyan]}, (#5)] &), 
    StreamPoints -> {Automatic, Scaled[#[[1]]]}, StreamScale -> Large,
     StreamStyle -> #[[2]]] & /@ {{0.01, "Line", 0.2}, {0.1, Thick, 
    0.5}}]
```

But I would like the thir argument in the style "definitions" here 0.2 and 0.5 to "multiply the argument #5 in the color function so that the two stream plots get different versions of the same color function, just different shades.